# How to join two queries in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two SQL queries that I want to join.

First query:

```
SELECT 
    rp_date, key_code, 
    sum(case when rp_id=15102 then rp_value else null end) as users_completed, 
    sum(case when rp_id=15108 then rp_value else null end) as users_inProgress 
FROM
    te_rp_pc_rate
WHERE
    abc_code = 'A204'
    AND organisation_id = '444-4'
    AND key_ code = '#KL0560' 
GROUP BY
    rp_date, key_code 
ORDER BY 
    rp_date DESC, key_code 
LIMIT 100;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
    cr_date  
    sum(case when rp_id=23101 then rp_value else null end) AS prim_kfc 
FROM
    te_emk_rate
WHERE 
    abc_code = 'A204'
    AND organisation_id = '444-4' 
    AND ref_value = 0
GROUP BY
    cr_date 
ORDER BY 
    cr_date DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

The dates (`cr_date`, `rp_date`) should be used for joining. For the first query's `rp_date` for the second `cr_date`.

The goal is to get the columns in a row for the same date. I've tried, but the results are too high.

Comment: can 'u share your version of join?

Comment: Here is my join
`SELECT e.cr_date, p.rp_date, p.key_code,
sum(case when p.rp_id=15102 then p.rp_value else null end) as users_ completed, 
sum(case when p.rp_id=15108 then p.rp_value else null end) as users_ inProgess,
sum(case when e.rp_id=23101 then e.rp_value else null end) as prim_kfc
FROM te_rp_pc_rate p,
te_emk_rate e
WHERE e.organisation_id = p.organisation_id
AND e.cr_date  = p.rp_date
AND p.organisation_id = '444-4'
AND e.abc_code = p.abc_code
AND p.abc_code = 'A204'
group BY e.cr_date, p.rp_date, p.key_code
order by p.rp_date desc, e.cr_date desc
LIMIT 100`

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using, because answers may very much depend on the DBMS.

Comment: I don't know which dbms is behind it. We work with cloud data hub

Answer (score 5):

You can put your queries into subqueries and join them. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT rp_date, key_code, 
        sum(case when rp_id=15102 then rp_value else null end) as users_completed, 
        sum(case when rp_id=15108 then rp_value else null end) as users_inProgress 
    from te_rp_pc_rate
    WHERE abc_code = 'A204'
        AND organisation_id = '444-4'
        AND key_ code = '#KL0560' 
    group by rp_date, key_code 
    Order By rp_date DESC, key_code 
    LIMIT 100;
) as q1

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cr_date, key_code  
    sum(case when rp_id=23101 then rp_value else null end) as prim_kfc 
    from te_emk_rate
    WHERE abc_code = 'A204'
    AND organisation_id = '444-4' 
    AND ref_value = 0
    group by cr_date, key_code 
    Order By cr_date DESC, key_code 
    LIMIT 100;
) as q2
on q1.rp_date = q2.cr_date
```

Comment: Correct. The OP must decide whether to use an inner, left outer or full outer join to get the results they are after.

Comment: I think i need an inner join